# Wrong Drop Down Menu on Page creation - html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have 4 drop down menus in my html code as show here. On page creation the drop down menu for factor drop down button should #dd3 and not #dd4. However I happen to get the wrong drop down menu for display. Any help on this? I have added the code below and @[jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/InaRUyO/1/):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container2{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: :123px;
    }





    </style>
    <title>Google Top Apps Trending</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            //var d = new Date();
            //var year = ["2013", "2014"];
            var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];



            var factors1 = new Array();
                factors1 = ["Version","Architecture","SDK Version","Target SDK","Phone to Tablet","Resolution"];


            for (i = 0; i < factors1.length; i++) {

                $("#dd3").append("<li><a href='#'>" + factors1[i] + "</a></li>");
            }


            var factors2 = new Array();
            var factors2 = ["IA Architecture Usage","Phone to Tablet"];


            for (i = 0; i < factors2.length; i++) {

                $("#dd4").append("<li><a href='#'>" + factors2[i] + "</a></li>");

            }

            for (i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {

                $("#dd1").append("<li><a href='#'>" + monthNames[i] + "</a></li>");
                $("#dd2").append("<li><a href='#'>" + monthNames[i] + "</a></li>");
            }


            $("#dd1 li a").click(function () {
                var selText = $(this).text();
                $("#monthFrom").text(selText);

            });

            $("#dd2 li a").click(function () {
                var selText = $(this).text();
                $("#monthTo").text(selText);

            });


            $("#dd3 li a").click(function () {
                var selText = $(this).text();
                $("#aspect").text(selText);

            });


            $("#dd4 li a").click(function () {
                var selText = $(this).text();
                $("#monthlyaspect").text(selText);

            });


            $("#monthly").click(function(){
                $("#monthTo").hide();
                $("#monthFrom").text("Choose a Month");
                $("#aspect").hide();
                $("#monthlyaspect").show();



            });


            $("#trend").show(function() { 

                $("#aspect").show();
                $("#monthlyaspect").hide();

            });
            $("#monthly").show(function() { 
                $("#aspect").hide();
                $("#monthlyaspect").show();

            });

            $("#trend").click(function(){
                $("#aspect").show();
                $("#monthTo").show();
                $("#monthFrom").text("Choose Month 1");
                $("#monthlyaspect").hide();


            });


        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

                <h3>Google App Analytics</h3>

                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">

                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#" id="monthly" >Monthly Analysis</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="trend">Trend Analyser</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="container1" class="well carousel-search hidden-phone">
                    <div class="btn-group"> <a id='monthFrom' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select1" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Choose Month 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd1" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group"> <a id='monthTo' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Choose Month 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd2" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="btn-group">    <a id='aspect' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select3" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Factor<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd3" class="dropdown-menu">


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="btn-group">    <a id='monthlyaspect' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select4" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Factor<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd4" class="dropdown-menu">


                        </ul>
                    </div>



                    <input id="btn1"  type="submit" class="btn" value="Analyze"   style="float: right;" />
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

drop down with id '#dd4' should be hidden when the page opens. It happens to display and the size of the items(drop down button) keeps changing too. Is there way i can fix the size of the drop down buttons. Sorry I'm totally new you to javascript. Hope somebody can give me a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you hide something with the hide() method and you show it using show()

For example to hide the #dd4 dropdown

```
$('#dd4').hide();
```

if you want to do somehting when #dd4 is hidden

```
    $('#dd4').hide(function(){
        $('#dd3').show();//to show the #dd3 dropdown on #dd4 hidden
    });
```

To show, replace show in the code!

To fix the dropdown size, you can use javascript but best practices tell us to do it within the css! So, add this css inside the  tag as follows

```
<style type="text/css">
  /*------*/
  ul.dropdown-menu,ul.dropdown-menu li{
       width:200px;//replace with the size you wish
       max-width:200px;//replace with the size you wish
  }


</style>
```

Complete code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container2{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: :123px;
}


  ul.dropdown-menu,ul.dropdown-menu li{
       width:200px;//replace with the size you wish
       max-width:200px;//replace with the size you wish
  }



</style>
<title>Google Top Apps Trending</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


            //var d = new Date();
            //var year = ["2013", "2014"];
                var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

      var factors1 = new Array();
 factors1 = ["Version","Architecture","SDK Version","Target SDK","Phone to Tablet","Resolution"];
        for (i = 0; i < factors1.length; i++) {
            $("#dd3").append("<li><a href='#'>" + factors1[i] + "</a></li>");
            }
            var factors2 = new Array();
            var factors2 = ["IA Architecture Usage","Phone to Tablet"];
            for (i = 0; i < factors2.length; i++) {
                 $("#dd4").append("<li><a href='#'>" + factors2[i] + "</a></li>");

            }

             for (i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {

                $("#dd1").append("<li><a href='#'>" + monthNames[i] + "</a></li>");
                $("#dd2").append("<li><a href='#'>" + monthNames[i] + "</a></li>");
            } 


             $("#dd1 li a").click(function () {
                 var selText = $(this).text();
                 $("#monthFrom").text(selText);

            });

             $("#dd2 li a").click(function () {
                var selText = $(this).text();
                $("#monthTo").text(selText);

            });


             $("#dd3 li a").click(function () {
                 var selText = $(this).text();
                 $("#aspect").text(selText);

            });


             $("#dd4 li a").click(function () {
                 var selText = $(this).text();
                 $("#monthlyaspect").text(selText);

             });
              $("#dd4).hide();//new line

             $("#monthly").click(function(){
                $("#monthTo").hide();
                $("#monthFrom").text("Choose a Month");
                $("#aspect").hide();
                $("#monthlyaspect").show();
                $("#dd4").show();////new line


            });


        $("#trend").show(function() { 

            $("#aspect").show();
            $("#monthlyaspect").hide();
            $("#dd4").hide();//new line

        });
        $("#monthly").show(function() { 
            $("#aspect").hide();
            $("#monthlyaspect").show();
            $("#dd4").show();//new line
        });

        $("#trend").click(function(){
            $("#aspect").show();
            $("#monthTo").show();
            $("#monthFrom").text("Choose Month 1");
            $("#monthlyaspect").hide();
            $("#dd4").hide();//new line

        });


    });

     </script>

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
              <div class="span12">                    

      <h3>Google App Analytics</h3>
               <div class="navbar"><div class="navbar-inner">

     <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" id="monthly" >Monthly Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="trend">Trend  Analyser</a></li>
     </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container1" class="well carousel-search hidden-phone">
                <div class="btn-group"> <a id='monthFrom' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select1" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Choose Month 1 <span class="caret"></span></a> <ul id="dd1" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group"> <a id='monthTo' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Choose Month 2 <span class="caret">   </span></a>  
                        <ul id="dd2" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="btn-group">    <a id='aspect' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select3" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Factor<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd3" class="dropdown-menu">


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="btn-group">    <a id='monthlyaspect' class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select4" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Factor<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="dd4" class="dropdown-menu">


                        </ul>
                    </div>



                <input id="btn1"  type="submit" class="btn" value="Analyze"   style="float: right;" />
                </div>

                </div>


            </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: I commented my lines as "//new line" so you can remove it if you don't need to show/hide the dd4 OR you can change dd4 into dd3 as well